# Kids’ show with toys to shoot at the on-screen images

Tags: story-identification, tv

What is the name of this kids’ show from the late 80s? It was based in space, and I think it was some sort of live-action TV show. Some of the images looked like TV static, and you could buy some toy spaceships shaped like a gun to shoot at the images (and somehow get hit) to gain or lose points.

I thought it was called "Captain Skyhawk", but apparently that's an old NES game.  Does anyone know what this show was called?

Comment: By "show" do you mean TV show?

Comment: Normally, I would say "we need more information"; but that entire concept of a toy gun to shoot at the TV makes it particularly easy to identify the TV show, given the information you provide. Thank you for enlightening me to  the existence of this show.

Comment: @Gnemlock, apparently not easy enough for me to identify/remember =)  Thanks for finding this.  I KNEW Captain was in the title

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### [Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092329/) (1987 - 1988)

Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future was a Canadian-American SciFi TV Series that ran from 1987 to 1988. The unique premise of this show was a line of interactive toys, some shaped like spaceships, that could be fired at different parts of the show.

Unfortunately, the show did not last very long; between the dark story-line, the live action violence and the interactivity provided to the children watching at home, the show was deemed to inappropriate for children, and cancelled. As such, it is listed as having *an entire season* of un-aired episodes. There has also been scarce rumour of a reboot.

Below, you can see an advertisement for one of the toys that were sold by Matel. As mentioned, these guns could be used to interact with the actual TV show.